# How stable is Cherokee Web Server?

Tags: web-server, cherokee

I just installed [Cherokee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherokee_HTTP_Server) and gave it a try. I'm pretty impressed with it. The configuration of the server is certainly a new approach and I must say that I generaly like it (surprisingly). Do you have any experience with it? Is it reliable?

Comment: I installed it a few days back. Have not played with it yet.

Answer (score 6):

I have implemented Cherokee at various sites and from the beginning it outperformed Apache, and gave a great administrator interface that everyone can use but requires a little read up regarding the rule evaluation. All problems are taken serious by the community, even the ones that are extremely hard to reproduce.

The highest uptime I had was around 50 days, and then I wanted to have the new release so I restarted it gracefully without any service window.

Comment: Still recommend it over Niginx?

Answer (score 3):

I have two production servers running Cherokee under CentOS 5.3 without trouble for more than a month. I recommend it, works wonderful!

Answer (score 3):

I totally recommend it.

I've personally seen how Cherokee fixed a whole lot of performance issues, at the same time that it made administration tasks much easier and straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

We run Cherokee on our Slicehost production instances and our development and staging machines. We have it fronting [web2py](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web2py) and for that purpose it is fantastic. Fast, reliable, easy to configure once you understand how it differs from what you know, like Apache.

Answer (score 2):

I have many Cherokee installation as well, mostly with Wordpress and Drupal but lately I installed one with Django. So far it has been working flawlessly along with memcached with 25-50k requests per day, which is not very high but I am working on a multiple locations and CDN project that is going to be 250k+ request per day and Cherokee will most likely be our main http server. On top of that the administration has never been easier. I also recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it very impressive. The support for streaming and geoip is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Cherokee as well and serve Wordpress (php fastcgi), Django (uWSGI) and Ruby on Rails (spawn-fgci) based projects on a cheap Rackspacecloud Server. It works perfect, I never had a Cherokee-related issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Cherokee since June on an Ubuntu dedicated server hosting my Web site called http://www.vehicall.com (mainly PERL scripts and JavaScript): it's quite fantastic for both speed and reliability points of vue !

Answer (score 0):

I use cherokee to host Django applications. Very stable and easy to deploy common apps

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cherokee as main http server in two servers for more than a year (php fcgi, recently php-fpm). Never failed me, seriously.

Server issues are resolved quickly, support is superior!